# Getting rid of blank space in web page

Tags: html

Please look at the bottom of following page:
http://javaexperience.com/this-and-super-in-java/

There is a large amount of blank space after the text "Initializing final variables in Java". I have seen the HTML code using Firebug but no clue which element is adding that extra blank space which makes the page look really bad.

Comment: Please take a screenshot and post it in your question. I don't see much of a gap at all.

Comment: are you calculating heights dyncamically, because everything seems fine until the code blocks are formatted, then your height breaks.

Comment: @Polynomial The gap appears once the code blocks are rendered.

Comment: @JonTaylor I see the code blocks, with syntax highlighting. I see no gap. Firefox 14.0.1

Comment: Try resetting the css. Put `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` at the top of the css file

Comment: @Polynomial fair enough, im sat on a test bed at moment running FF 6 on ubuntu lol so I'm a little behind on versions on here.

Comment: @polynomial: I see the gap and I'm on 14.0.1. It is script generated so either you have script off or there is something environmental that determines what the script does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because `sidebar` is taller than `contents-b` and this seems in no small part due to the rather unusual `<b class="niftyfill" style="height: 670px;"></b>` that seems to exist at the end of there. It seems to be dynamically added (ie firebug shows it to me in the dom inspection but it doesn't appear in source) but I'm not sure what by or why. Hopefully you are aware of whatever script you are running to do this...

Comment: thanks. the advertisement in sidebar was the culprit. I fixed it.